# Prolog beginner level, word logic

Tags: prolog

I've started a Prolog course and I've been given the following word problem as homework. I'm fine with understanding arithmetic problems, but I'm struggling to get this word problem right. I've pasted my solution, but it only succeeds for the first test and not the second test. Could you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong? In the textbook, problems with "every person" often use the _ to indicate it could be anyone, so I'm wondering if that is what I'm missing? Or is my logic just wrong? Thanks!

*Write a predicate eats_all(Person, Food) that takes a list of people Person and a list of items Food and succeeds if every person in Person eats every item in Food, according to the predicate eats(Name, Item). It will succeed if either Person or Food is empty. 
Test cases:*

```
?- eats_all([john,tony],[pizza,burgers]).
true
?- eats_all([],[tacos]).
true
```

Facts:

```
eats(melissa, pizza).
eats(melissa, pies).
eats(melissa, hotdogs).
eats(tony, burgers).
eats(tony, pizza).
eats(john, pizza).
eats(john, burgers).
```

My solution so far:

```
% the first person in Person list eats all foods in Food list (sub-problem);
first_person(_, []).
first_person(X, [Head_Food|Tail_Food]) :-
    eats(X, Head_Food),
    first_person(X, Tail_Food).

% main problem
eats_all([], _).            
eats_all([Head_Person|Tail_Person], [Head_Food|Tail_Food]):-   
    eats(Head_Person, Head_Food),  
    eats_all(Tail_Person, Tail_Food).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost get there. For you are new to prolog, it's good to break the problem into subproblems. First, lets think recursively:

```
- Base case: eats_all(_, []). and eats_all([], _).
- Recursive case: 
      + the first person in Person list eats all foods in Food (here is a subproblem); 
      + recursive call of the function eats_all for the rest of Person list.

% sub-problem: succeed if a person X eats all foods in Food
eat_all_food(_, []).
eat_all_food(X, [F|Fs]) :-
eats(X, F),
eat_all_food(X, Fs).

% main problem: succeed if all persons in Person eat all foods in Food
eats_all([], _).
eats_all(_, []).
eats_all([X|Xs], Y) :-
   eat_all_food(X, Y),
   eats_all(Xs, Y).
```

One more thing: using _ only means that you don't care what the value of parameter is (as seen in the base case, when Food is an empty list, the function always returns true regardless of Person).

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks tudatn. I've tried putting together a sub-problem above the main problem. This way seems to pass the two tests, but there are so few tests given it could be a coincidence. Does that look right to you, or am I supposed to combine the two parts using a 3rd bit of code? Thanks for your help - the textbooks for Prolog are not that good.

Comment: Your recursive case is not correct. Takes a look at my edit answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just can't get that working according to your edits. When I do it that way I get the wrong answers, such as: eats_all([john,tony],[pizza,burgers]). is now false. It should be true.

Comment: Mine returns true with your given example. I will put all functions together in my edit answer. Lets see if it works for you :).

Comment: Thanks so much - that works perfectly. I don't know what it was before, but this time everything is right. I really appreciate your help. I can't upvote this answer though because it says new members can't vote. I can give it a green tick though. Thanks.